# Partial derivative of the CDF is equal to the PDF

Tags: cumulative-distribution-functions

Consider
$$F(\theta;q;\beta)=\Phi\left(-\frac{\Phi^{-1}(q)-\Phi^{-1}(\theta)\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}{\beta}\right)$$
where $\theta$ denotes the default rate in the portfolio, and $\Phi(\cdot)$ the cumulative distribution function of an $N(0,1)$ variable.

Show that
\begin{align*}
    f(\theta;q;\beta)& =\frac{\partial F(\theta;q;\beta)}{\partial\theta}\\
    & = \frac{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}{\beta}\cdot e^{-\frac{(\Phi^{-1}(q)-\Phi^{-1}(\theta)\sqrt{1-\beta^2})^2}{2\beta^2}+\frac{\Phi^{-1}(\theta)}{2}}.
\end{align*}

Hint: First show that
$$\frac{\partial\Phi^{-1}(\theta)}{\partial\theta} = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\theta))}.$$

**Solution**
So this is my solution.
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial\Phi^{-1}(q)}{\partial\theta}& =\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\Phi^{-1}(\theta)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx\right)\\
    & \overset{1}{=}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\Phi^{-1}(\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx\right)\\
    & \overset{2}{=}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\Phi^{-1}(\theta)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(\Phi^{-1}(\theta))}\right)\\
    & \overset{3}{=}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\Phi^{-1}(\theta))^2}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(\Phi^{-1}(\theta))}\\
    & \overset{4}{=}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\theta))\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(\Phi^{-1}(\theta))}\\
    & \overset{6}{=} \frac{1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\theta))}
\end{align*}
However I think I have made a error somewhere since the equals sign number $6$ is just me knowing (guessing) what the answer is. Can anyone help?

Comment: tru, but some of my fellow student asked our lecturer if this just was a one liner and he said he wanted to se more, what ever that means.

Answer (score 1):

The first fact is:
$$\tag{1}
\Phi'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,.
$$
The formula in your hint is wrong. The correct statement of that hint is (derivative of an inverse function) another [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_rule):
$$\tag{2}
\frac{\partial \Phi^{-1}(\theta)}{\partial \theta}=\frac{1}{\Phi'(\Phi^{-1}(\theta))}\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$\tag{3}
\frac{\partial \Phi^{-1}(\theta)}{\partial \theta}=\sqrt{2\pi}\,\exp\Big(\frac{(\Phi^{-1}(\theta))^2}{2}\Big)\,.
$$
Next, by the chain rule,
\begin{align}\tag{4}
\frac{\partial F(\theta,q,\beta)}{\partial\theta}=\Phi'\Bigg( -\frac{\Phi^{-1}(q)-\Phi^{-1}(\theta)\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}{\beta}\Bigg)\,\frac{\partial \Phi^{-1}(\theta)}{\partial \theta}\frac{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}{\beta}\,.
\end{align}
Can you proceed ?